# Use getters and setters to Control Access to an Object

Tags: javascript

I'm aware that a very similar question has been asked however in the other question with the similar title of this one the user has the code wrapped in a function titled makeClass. I believe my question is less complicated because I do not have the code wrapped in a function. So i figured it would be ok to ask the question again? My apologies if the question is too similar thus creating redundant inquiries.

According to the directions I need to write a class which has a constructor that takes in a temperature in Fahrenheit and with getters and setters the class should be able to turn farenheit into celcius. I will paste directions directly from assignment incase I may be missing something. Im confused as to if the class should be able to turn temperature into farenheit if celcius is passed and vice versa or am I only changing farenheit into celcius?

**Directions from assignment**
Use the class keyword to create a Thermostat class. The constructor accepts a Fahrenheit temperature.

In the class, create a getter to obtain the temperature in Celsius and a setter to set the temperature in Celsius.

Remember that C = 5/9 * (F - 32) and F = C * 9.0 / 5 + 32, where F is the value of temperature in Fahrenheit, and C is the value of the same temperature in Celsius.

Note: When you implement this, you will track the temperature inside the class in one scale, either Fahrenheit or Celsius.

This is the power of a getter and a setter. You are creating an API for another user, who can get the correct result regardless of which one you track.

In other words, you are abstracting implementation details from the user.

**additional notes**

```
Thermostat should be a class with a defined constructor method.

Passed
class keyword should be used.

Passed
Thermostat should be able to be instantiated.

When instantiated with a Fahrenheit value, Thermostat should set the correct temperature.

Passed
A getter should be defined.

Passed
A setter should be defined.

Calling the setter with a Celsius value should set the temperature.
```

---

From the directions I believe I should be able to turn farenheit to celcius or celcius to farenheit. I cannot understand how to do this problem and any help is appreciated. Here is what I wrote so far:

```
// Only change code below this line
class Thermostat {
  static celcius;
  constructor(fTemp) {
    this.fTemp = fTemp;
  }

  set temperature(fTemp) {
    this.celcius = (5 / 9) * (fTemp - 32);
  }

  get temperature() {
    return this.celcius;
  }
}
// Only change code above this line

const thermos = new Thermostat(76); // Setting in Fahrenheit scale
let temp = thermos.temperature; // 24.44 in Celsius
thermos.temperature = 26;
temp = thermos.temperature; // 26 in Celsius
```

Comment: This hint is important: `you will track the temperature inside the class in one scale, either Fahrenheit or Celsius.` You track both `fTemp` and `celsius`, which is wrong. Pick just one.

Comment: What's wrong with your code right now? What do you want us to do?

Comment: @Spectic I need to write a class Thermostat with a constructor that takes in a degree of Fahrenheit value and be ale to crate a new object that can return Celsius. I believe these are the test results that I need to be able to make work:                               
const thermos = new Thermostat(76); // Setting in Fahrenheit scale
let temp = thermos.temperature; // 24.44 in Celsius
thermos.temperature = 26;
temp = thermos.temperature; // 26 in Celsius

Answer (score 0):

The get function should return the celsius value while the set function is setting temperature and updating the fahrenheit and converting the celsius value passed before to fahrenheit.

Take a look at the codes below

```
class Thermostat{
  constructor(fahrenheit){
    this.fahrenheit = fahrenheit;
  }
  get temperature(){
    return (5 / 9) * (this.fahrenheit - 32);
  }

  set temperature(celsius){
    this.fahrenheit = (celsius * 9.0) / 5 + 32;
  }
}
```